# Cannot Windows+Tab in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I recently upgraded my ubuntu from 10.10 to 11.04. I use to issue the shortcut Windows+Tab key in my previous ubuntu version and the windows will be shown graphically through which I use to switch. But now that is gone!. Windows+Tab key does nothing. Do I have to do something to enable it back or I have to live with this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because at Natty Mod4/Super is a shortcut to Unity panel. You can change that at Compiz.

1) Install [Compiz Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

2) Open:

```
ccsm
```

3) Go to Unity and change the shortcut as you like to free your shortcut:

[image]

At this example I've changed from <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Now your mod key is free to use as you like.

Comment: That helped me fix my problem. Thanks desgua !!

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 4):

With ConpizConfig Settings Manager, turn on Shift Switcher. Its Next Window and Previous Window commands - `<Super>Tab` and `<Shift><Super>Tab` - are what do it. I had it enabled in 10.10 and it (along with a few others) was disabled after upgrading to 11.04.